# Количество чисел в тексте и максимальное из них

Tags: python

> Дан произвольный текст. Напечатайте все имеющиеся в нем цифры, определите их количество, сумму и найти максимальное.

Знаю как найти сумму:

```
s='aa3aBbb6ccc'
total=0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i].isalpha(): 
        continue 
    total=total+int(s[i]) 
print ("сумма чисел:", total)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы отличить цифру, можно воспользоваться методом `isdigit()`.

***Пример:***

```py
def main():
    s = 'aa3aBbb6ccc'

    digits = [int(char) for char in s if char.isdigit()]  # listcomp
    print(*digits)      # Цифры
    print(len(digits))  # Количество цифр
    print(sum(digits))  # Сумма цифр
    print(max(digits))  # Максимальная цифра


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
3 6
2
9
6
```